# pointer to structure to pointer to structure

Tags: c

I can't get it work!
Throws seg fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t NbOfElmts; 

    float  * Weights; 
    int    * Areas;

} ListOfCoeff;

typedef struct
{
    size_t NbOfElmts;  

    ListOfCoeff * Elmts;


} SetOfListsOfCoeff;



int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

   SetOfListsOfCoeff * theList;

   int N = 10;
   float *A = malloc( N * sizeof(*A) );

   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        A[ i ] = i;


   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
       ( (theList[ i ].Elmts)->Weights)[ i ] = A[ i ];


   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        printf("\n List = %f", ( (theList[ i ].Elmts)->Weights)[ i ] );

return 0;


}
```

The problem in the line:

```
( (theList[ i ].Elmts)->Weights)[ i ] = A[ i ];
```

Comment: This is a side issue but:
    int N = 10;
    float *A = malloc( N * sizeof(*A) );
Means the pointer to a float 'A' points at 10 times the size of a pointer to a float. I think that you meant sizeof(float) not pointer to float.

Comment: @MatthewVCarey it looks correct to me, maybe you overlooked the `*` in the sizeof expression

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was getting my * in a twist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not allocated any memory for theList.